# Using Box with JWT (Server Authentication)

Tags: jwt, box

I using Box API JWT Server Authentication:

```
        IAccessTokenCache accessTokenCache = new InMemoryLRUAccessTokenCache(100);

        Reader reader = new FileReader("D:\\config.json");
        BoxConfig boxConfig = BoxConfig.readFrom(reader);


        BoxAPIConnection api = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(USER_ID,boxConfig);
```

but the Box exception:

```
{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"This app is not authorized by the enterprise admin"}
```

[image]

Comment: You can Authorize New App here:
[https://app.box.com/master/custom-apps](https://app.box.com/master/custom-apps) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWlj4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWlj4.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The admin of Box has to go to Admin Console -> Enterprise Settings -> Apps and authorize your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can give you a look at the steps,how to Apps and authorize may app

Comment: In the JWT apps list, if you click on the elipses, select "authorize"

Answer (score 8):

@kendomen is correct.  Here's some more detail:

Go to api.box.com.  Then select Admin Console.

[image]

Now this is where it gets funky. Click on the Security step.

[image]

Then the fine print.

[image]

This gives the tool bar that should have been displayed three steps ago.  Click Apps.

[image]

Then click on Authorize New App.

[image]

This puts up a pop-up where you enter the app key.  This is referred to as the "ClientID" in the json file you may have downloaded from Box.com.

[image]

Comment: There is a slight change in the UI now,
 it's located under Business Settings (https://monosnap.com/file/1GtysqvkwMh0gWsbpiRYnvswdGPw68.png)